# How to ignore control keys output while logging from screen or script command in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen

While logging screen output in linux from script or screen command, it also logs the control keys output. Like ESC, BS (backspace), Arrow Keys, previous command history, etc.

Example:

```
^H^H^H^H^[[1Pall^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G^G
```

How can I log the screen output, without logging the control keys output?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But you can view the log file by `less -r` if you don't want to see the control codes.